# Pass sudo Ansible-Playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I need to install any program as evidence, I'm trying with FileZilla. I have two virtual machines that are seen and  Ansible works. Thanks to another question I've done tell me that I must indicate that you have to do as a user sudo, but not how to indicate the password.

My playbook is as follows:

[image]

The current error:

[image]

As the playbook should be? Or how do I launch the execution command? I have tried the following ways:

`$ ansible-playbook -s playbook.yml`
`$ ansible-playbook -U playbook.yml`
`$ ansible-playbook -S playbook.yml`
`$ ansible-playbook -b playbook.yml`
`$ ansible-playbook -k playbook.yml`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I've commented on your previous post.
It will be simpler if you do not use a sudo password.

My sudoers allows members of the admin group sudo access without a password:

`%admin     ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

If you have to use a sudo password, you can prompt for the password with `-K`

`$> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -K`

As for supplying the password as an argument, you can use `--extra-vars`

`$> ansible-playbook playbook.yml --extra-vars 'ansible_become_pass="abc123"'`

I have not been able to use this method as my password contains '@' and '!' characters and I've tried escaping, using JSON etc. but I did not get it to work.
Simpler alpha-numeric characters work fine.